# Solutions to polynomial with cos coefficient

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, polynomials, fourier-analysis

I'm wondering whether the following identities are true, and I have a basic idea of how the proof would go, but would like to confirm my thoughts.

The first one is: Let $\{p_n(r)\}$ be a set of polynomials of variable $r$, then the solution $r_0$ to
$$p_0(r) + p_1(r)\cos\theta +p_2(r)\cos^2\theta + \cdots + p_n(r)\cos^n\theta = 0$$
is independent of $\theta$ iff $r_0$ solves all $p_0(r),...,p_n(r)$.

The second one is a modified version of it: Let $\{p_n(r)\}$ be a set of polynomials of variable $r$, and let $k_1,...,k_n$ be independent of $\theta$, then the solution to
$$p_0(r) + p_1(r)\cos(\theta-k_1) +p_2(r)\cos(2\theta-k_2) + \cdots + p_n(r)\cos(n\theta-k_n) = 0$$
is independent of $\theta$ iff the solution solves all $p_0(r),...,p_n(r)$.

I think both of these would be true. The first statement would somehow be link to that $\{\cos^n(\theta)\}$ is a basis of the functional space (? I'm not sure tho). And to see the second one we convert $\cos(n\theta-k_n)=\frac1{2}(e^{k_n}e^{-in\theta}+e^{-k_n}e^{in\theta})$, so that in the end $k_n$ only amounts to a constant coefficient to each level of $e^{in\theta}$.

Any thoughts?

Comment: My first thought is that if some solution $x$ is such that $p_0(x),p_1(x),\dots,p_n(x)$ all equal zero, then any combination of those polynomials, regardless of what you're doing with $\theta$ and $\theta-k$ etc. this $x$ will still solve those, since we would have all zeros (as $x$ is a root to the $p_i$) times whatever other junk there is, and that junk wouldn't matter one bit

Comment: @IdioticShrike: Note that it's an "iff" claim and the "only if" direction is less trivial.

Comment: @Troposphere I suppose that if $x$ were not a root to all the polynomials, and since each polynomial is being scaled differently, it would be necessary to choose some $\theta$ to make the non-zero polynomials cancel out i.e. a sloppily phrased proof of the iff

Comment: @IdioticShrike I think I want the root to the polynomial to stay constant regardless of how theta changes, and I'm wondering whether this is possible only if this root is a solution to all coefficient of powers of cos.

Answer (score 1):

Yes I am pretty confident that if some $x$ is a root of all the $p_i$ then $\theta$ can vary however it wishes, and if $x$ is NOT a root to all the $p_i$ then $\theta$ must be chosen very specifically so that it removes the non-zero terms i.e $\theta$ becomes dependent. For example, suppose $x$ is not a root to $p_0,p_1$ but is a root for the others.

Then we would get $$p_0(x)+p_1(x)\cdot\cos(\theta)+0+0+\dots+0$$ and we want that equal to zero so $\theta$ would need to be something specific, depending on $x$: $\arccos(-\frac{p_0(x)}{p_1(x)})$

Another example, using the second equation: $x$ is a root of $p_0,p_2$ and $p_n$.

Then we would get $$p_0(x)+0+p_2(x)\cdot\cos(2\theta-k_2)+0+0+\dots+p_n(x)\cdot\cos(n\theta-k_n)$$ which we want equal to zero: $\theta$ again must very specifically solve this, now viewing $p_0(x),p_2(x),p_n(x)$ as constants that have been evaluated. If $\theta$ did not depend on $x$ in a case where $x$ is not a root to all solutions then it would be very easy to find $\theta$ such that the sum was not zero - in my first example, a choice of $\theta=\pi/2$ would have zeroed out all terms with a $\cos\theta$, leaving $p_0(x)=0$ which wasn't the case.